# TypeScript: Element implicitly has an 'any' type for RegExp

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, implicit-conversion

So, I want to create a function that would take a duration string (e.g `12ms`, `7.5 MIN`, `400H`), parse it and convert it to milliseconds.

```js
const units = {
  MS: 1,
  S: 1 * 1000,
  MIN: 60 * 1 * 1000,
  H: 60 * 60 * 1 * 1000
}

export function toMS(str: string): number {
  let regex = /^(?<number>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s*(?<unit>MS|S|MIN|H))?$/i

  if (!regex.test(str)) {
    throw new TypeError(`Expected a duration, got: ${str}`)
  }

  let match = str.match(regex)

  let number = Number(match?.groups?.number)
  let unit = (match?.groups?.unit || 'ms').toUpperCase()

  return Math.floor(number * units[unit])
}
```

So, function `toMS()` takes a string, tests if the provided string is valid (`number` + `whitespace (optional)` + `unit abbr (optional)`) and if it's valid - parses it using `str.match(regex)`.

Everything works fine until: `units[unit]`. It gives me an error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`.

I've had the same error before with function arguments & class constructors and it was easy to solve since the user provides data. But now I have no idea how to solve that, cause I can't force `str.match(regex).groups.unit` to have a specific type like `: 'MS | S | MIN | H`.

I know that it is also possible to create *tsconfig.json* with `"noImplicitAny": false` but in my case that's not good at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript has no way of knowing whether your regex will really match `MS|S|MIN|H`. This is [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) territory, and TypeScript is not that powerful yet.

The only thing TypeScript knows is that what you've matched is going to be a `string`, because both `match?.groups?.unit` and `'ms'` expressions yield `string`.

What you can do is letting TypeScript know that your `units` is an object with keys of type `string` and values of type `number`, and check whether what you've matched is a property on the `units` object. Like this:

```js
const units: { [k: string]: number } = { // letting TypeScript know
  MS: 1,
  S: 1 * 1000,
  MIN: 60 * 1 * 1000,
  H: 60 * 60 * 1 * 1000,
};

export function toMS(str: string): number {
  const regex = /^(?<number>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s*(?<unit>MS|S|MIN|H))?$/i;

  if (!regex.test(str)) {
    throw new TypeError(`Expected a duration, got: ${str}`);
  }

  const match = str.match(regex);
  const number = Number(match?.groups?.number);
  const unit = (match?.groups?.unit || 'ms').toUpperCase();

  if (unit in units) { // checking whether your matched string is something you can handle, in runtime
    return Math.floor(number * units[unit]);
  } else {
    throw new Error(`couldn't find units! :(`);
  }
}
```